# Correct implementation of ACL layer for external service call in .NET

Tags: .net, rest, domain-driven-design, acl

I am developing a c# application and I need to connect to an external service via rest api
Since the external service is being developed by another company, I decided to use the ACL layer. But I can not be sure of the correctness of the chosen architecture.

I have isolated project MyApplicationName.ExternalServiceName.Client (infrastructure layer) which is used by MyApplicationName.Application project (application layer).

[image]

With this configuration, I have an application dependency on infrastructure, which is not correct, in order to solve this problem, **should I place the client interface in the application layer and change the external service dependency on application?**

[image]

It seems to work, but in that case **what about external packages**? if an external company provides a ready nuget package with their client, should my application layer depend on the external package? is it correct? (or it might only work semantically and if I only use abstractions it doesn't matter.

[image]

**Also I have a question about ACL mapping? does it have to be at the application layer? or infrastructure level?** (I see a clear advantage of implementing mapping in the infrastructure layer, so that we can completely hide the domain level of the external client in the infrastructure layer and it will never get into our business logic)

[image]

but is it right?

Answer (score 0):

> But I can not be sure of the correctness of the chosen architecture.

An architecture does not have *inherent* "correctness". An architecture can be correct or incorrect in achieving a specific objective you have (confidentiality, maintainability, ...). Your first step should be to explicit what challenge you are facing so you can consider your architectural responses and their correctness.

The purpose of an ACL is to mitigate volatility and/or complexity of an external system by exposing a simple and stable alternative to that external system. An ACL is a good architecture response to the need to prevent a legacy system from "contaminating" a modern system with using concepts that are not relevant and would render it largerly more complex than needed and drag it down into the "legacyness". It is also a good response to the need to decouple your new system from a dependency reference on a highly unstable external system interface. If you are facing such encounters, then yes using an ACL is a good architectural response to your concerns.

ACL is based on the concept of component software development. A component is a piece of software composed with 2 parts : a public interface and a private implementation. The interface should be stable and simple to protect the application from the volatility and/or complexity of the external system. The ACL private implementation is an adapter between the simple and stable public interface of the ACL and the volatile and/or complex interface of the legacy system ; it's that part that does the actual conversion between both systems.

All your diagrams are incorrect in that purpose, as none of them isolate your application from the external service. The ACL should split into two components, and your application should depend on your ACL's interface only. The ACL's implementation, should implement an adapter pattern, depending on both the ACL's interface and the external service's interface :

[image: ACL diagram]

This way, the application depends on a simple and stable ACL interface, while you may change the ACL's private implementation to hide complexity and volatility of the external system from your application as frequently as required, without impacting the rest of your application.

Any 3rd party nuget package that is provided by your external system editor shall be referenced by the ACL's implementation :

[image: ACL with client]